# Delphi 11 - scaling and font size problems

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a VCL application that works fine with D10.4. Created with D11, all elements of the form are displayed greatly enlarged at runtime.

Depending on the project settings (Project/Options/Manifest) you can make the program run on the development computer with a 4K monitor in the specified font (everything set to 8 points).

If you start the same program on an HD monitor, all elements except the main menu (!) are displayed in a larger font.

Windows settings on the 4K: 200% scaling, on the HD: 100%

The Delphi has all patches up to 2/22.

The exe, created with 10.4, runs perfectly on both test computers.

Is there a solution for this or do I actually have to build an own environment for VCL apps?

Is there maybe a hidden option to disable all this scaling stuff?

Thanks for every hint!

Many greetings

Comment: Delphi 11 offers a start menu entry *Delphi 11 (DPI unaware)*. Can you try if it works with that one?

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe, this is a helpful workaround. With this switch, the buggy scaling stuff is disabled and the executable  runs on most devices.
But: all ontrols, not listenig for 'parent font setting' (e.g. dbgrids) need to be modified by manually.
And: scaling does still not work like before on 10.4 (e.g. monitor2-mode does not work at all).

Thanks for your help! :)